# Change TextView if Spinner or EditText changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm a beginner at android development. I have a `TextView`, `Spinner` and `EditText`. The `TextView` will change according to `Spinner` or `EditText` and I know how to do that. 
My problem is how to make both `Spinner` and `EditText` like work together, so when I select an item from the `Spinner` it will check what I have in `EditText` before print it in the `TextView`, and it has to be the same for `EditText`.

`EditText` code.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!mEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());

                mTextView.setText(value + "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Spinner code:

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mMapUnit.containsKey(lengthKey[position])) {
                if (!mEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    value = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());

                    // calculate

                    mTextView.setText(result + "");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to put the text of the editext and the selected item in the TextView

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!mEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());

                mTextView.setText(value + "" + mSpinner.getAdapter().getItem(mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mMapUnit.containsKey(lengthKey[position])) {
                if (!mEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    value = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());

                    // calculate

                    mTextView.setText(value + "" + mSpinner.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

A little explaination of the code above:

I suppose you know what an Adapter is, nevertheless I'm going to explain it;
An adapter is an object that holds the information that needs to be displayed in a View (in this case a Spinner).

That adapter is attached to the Spinner view, and by calling the method 
mSpinner **.getAdapter()**

You'll get that very instance of the adapter that is attached to the Spinner. 
Because the Spinner heavily works together with the adapter, the position of an item in the Spinner will be at the same position in the adapter.

So you can call mSpinner.getAdapter()**.getItem(position);** to get the item on the position *position*.

Then you should see what the adapter uses for ListTypes. If it's a string you can do

String itemText = **((String)** mSpinner.getAdapter().getItem(position) **)** ;

When the onTextChanged callback is called, the text of the EditText changes (or is changed) and it doesn't think about the Spinner. So you don't get parameters of the Spinner (such as the current position or id). Thus you'll need to get it manually with the explaination above.

When the OnItemSelected callback is called, the Spinner changed, and as you may guess by now, this time we do have those parameters I've talked about. So you don't need to get the selected item (which is dangerous because the Spinner can still be processing the change and the selectedItem of the spinner can be different from the position that is supplied by the callback)

So you must use the position parameter of the callback.

Since I couldn't find the "result" variable, I've assumed that you meant the "value" variable in the OnItemSelectedListener.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use boolean variable to check conditions for EditText or Spinner.
create boolean with default value false for both Spinner and EditText.
in afterTextChanged sub method of TextWatcher and in Spinner set its boolean to true and in other side (Spinner and EditText) check that.

maybe this help.